# EF6 SQL column update concurrency

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a requirement for one of my columns:

If StatusId is Rejected then don't allow any other status (Verify, Pending etc)

I have checks in BL to not allow this but if changes are made from different DB contexts then it's of no use.

Short of implementing a cache, is there a way to enforce this behavior inside SQL server?

Comment: You could have a trigger instead of update, that could have the logic in there, and return an error if the condition is not met.

Comment: Yes, seems like what I was looking for. Thanks